# How do I create a domain alias in drupal?

Tags: drupal, wamp

I am using drupal 9. I have a multisite in drupal 7 but it is not a good solution, because I have more than 100 sites and is very difficult to maintain. So I want to have a single site with different sections and I would like that each section to have its own domain.

For example, I want to convert this:

```
https://mydomain/mysection
```

To this:

```
https://mysection.mydomain
```

I'm working in my computer with wamp. I tried the domain path module but I can't get it to work. I added the virtual host and point it to the drupal installation, then I added the domain alias, but when I try it, it just load the home page.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution here is not to use the "Domain Path" module, but the "Domain"-Module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/domain

Here you can find a short instruction Video for the Module

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_rP74-GFFQ